# Hermite polynomials and Fubini theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, special-functions

Working with Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$, I'm faced with the problem to interchange  sums and integral in this expression

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \sum_n \sum_m \frac{H_n(x)}{n!}s^n \; \frac{H_m(x)}{m!}t^m  \; e^{-x^2}\right )dx $$

My idea is to use twice Fubini theorem (the sum can be seen as an integral with the counting measure), but I can't prove that

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \sum_n \sum_m \left\lvert{ \frac{H_n(x)}{n!}s^n \; \frac{H_m(x)}{m!}t^m}  \right\lvert \; e^{-x^2}\right )dx \; < +\infty$$